# Google Sheet add-on onInstall() and onOpen() not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to create an add-on for Google Sheets, but running in the problem.

The add-on creates additional menu in "Add-on" menu using `onOpen()` function of Google Drive API, but it does not do that `onInstall()`. So I have been told to add the folloing

```js
function onInstall(e) {
   onOpen(e)
}
```

now, what I have tried to do is the following, but it still does not work

```js
    function onInstall() {
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
          .addItem('Browse My Add-on', 'browseMyAddOn')
          .addToUi();
    }

    function onOpen() {
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
          .addItem('Browse My Add-on', 'browseMyAddOn')
          .addToUi();
    }
```

Please help me

Comment: This question needs to be clarified. What are the symptoms that you see that have you concluding "it doesn't work"? Have you examined the execution transcript to see if the script has run, and if so, where any failure occurred?

Comment: Your code is almost identical to what I have in my published add-on, it should work. Have you been through the approval process with your add-on? If not, then while add-ons are in developer preview, it will probably not install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Sheets & Docs Script fails to create add-on menu when add-on is installed from Chrome store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235886/google-sheets-docs-script-fails-to-create-add-on-menu-when-add-on-is-installed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try this one instead:

```
function onInstall(e) {
   onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Browse My Add-on', 'browseMyAddOn')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already just before I posted my question in the order that you have submitted in your answer and in reverse too as suggested on one of Google help forums, but nothing seems to work. Looks like it is a bug of some sort with Google API. I have also send email to them to see if this is true so they can investigate it further.

Comment: Well. Could you find some usefull information from the link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle

Comment: I do not mean to offend, but this does not even try to answer the question - there is no functional difference between having `onInstall` call `onOpen`, vs duplicating the code as in the original question.

Comment: I have now found the problem, the problem is that I needed to same my add-on as a new version first before publishing it. So both versions of the code in the original question and in the answer is correct.

Comment: So, to help future users, you should delete all three of your questions, since they are not relevant to your actual problem.

Comment: Had same problem where I followed the example and reversed the order. Problem solved after putting onInstall first.