# Google Apps Script menu item not appearing after publishing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon, triggers

--EDIT--
As it turns out everything I wrote worked (well enough for my purposes). The problem was that when publishing the script I neglected to change the version number when publishing so no changes were updated on Google's system. I found the resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235886/google-sheets-docs-script-fails-to-create-add-on-menu-when-add-on-is-installed?rq=1).

--ORIGINAL POST--
I've got a script I've been writing and am now ready to publish it. In my script I am able to use the Add-ons menu to run the script just fine, however when I publish and install the add-on my custom menu items don't appear. I've tried everything I can think of and still nothing seems to work. I've seen some people saying that there is an error that will appear in the Chrome console, but I don't get anything of the sort.

Here is my code to create the menu:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  menu.addItem('Run', 'main');
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

I have tried both of the ways that Google described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), but neither of them showed the menu, however the latter example did kick back the error "Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call fetch" on the original, unpublished version of the add-on

This is my first add-on so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, it works in Test run for all modes, but post-install menu item does not show until I refresh the sheet. Have posted an issue  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153373886