# Authorization Lifecycle on published add-on is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Have a problem with my add-on that should, but not creating a menu items in Add-ons on Google Sheets and Docs on install from the store until the page is refreshed.

According to Google Support I should look in to the following:

"Usually this is caused by a problem with the Authorization Lifecycle, specifically the opening stage.

The most common culprit is a global variable in the code that tries to access Google services without authorization, like:

var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

See the documentation:

Warning: When your onOpen(e) function runs, the entire script is loaded and any global statements are executed. These statements execute under the same authorization mode as onOpen(e) and will fail if the mode prohibits them. This preventsonOpen(e) from running. If your published add-on fails to add its menu items, look in the browser's JavaScript console to see if an error was thrown, then examine your script to see whether the onOpen(e) function or global variables call services that aren't allowed in AuthMode.NONE."

I have no idea what and how should I deal with this as my add-on was not created by me. I can do minor things, but this is something that I cannot handle on my own and really need your help please.

Hear is my script:

```
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Browse Templates', 'browseTemplates')
      .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function browseTemplates(){
    collectBasicData();
   // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
   var htmlOutput = HtmlService
   .createTemplateFromFile("Gallery").evaluate()
   .setWidth(700)
   .setHeight(510);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Spreadsheet123 - Template Vault');
}

function collectAllData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
  DATA = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return DATA;
}

function collectBasicData(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(PIVOT_SHEET);
  var tabSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(TAB_SHEET);
  BASIC_DATA = {
    "tab_about" : getValue(tabSheet,"B1"),
    "tab_help": getValue(tabSheet,"B2"),
    "pivot":sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  };
  return false;
}

function getValue(sheet,addr){
  return sheet.getRange(addr).getValue().toString().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}

function createACopy(id){
  var docName = DocsList.getFileById(id).getName();
  return DocsList.getFileById(id).makeCopy(docName).getUrl();
}

function insertInCurrent(id){
    var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets();
    for(var i=0;i<sourceSheets.length;i++){
        var sheetName = sourceSheets[i].getName();
        var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(sheetName);
        source.copyTo(destinationSpreadSheet).setName(sheetName);
    }
}
```

I have looked in to the documentation on Google, but cannot understand how and where I should use it in my script.

Your help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: You say you want this to work on Docs and Sheets. The code in `onOpen()` is written only for Sheets. Is your problem that it isn't working for *Docs*?  Also - the blah-api tags aren't relevant to the question, and should be deleted.

Comment: Duplicate for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235886/google-sheets-docs-script-fails-to-create-add-on-menu-when-add-on-is-installed

Comment: Also a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138535. All by the same user, day after day. @AlexB: if the first answer wasn't what you expected, do as suggested [here](https://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html#no_repeats): do some more research and improve your original question. If people trying to help ask for more details, edit the question to provide it.

Comment: I am sorry for posting duplicate question, the problem was that I needed to actually save my add-on as anew version before publishing it to the Chrome store, therefore all changes were simply ignored, but now all works just fine. Thanks to all of you who has tried to help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets & Docs Script fails to create add-on menu when add-on is installed from Chrome store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235886/google-sheets-docs-script-fails-to-create-add-on-menu-when-add-on-is-installed)